# Device discovery in FIWARE IoTAgent-JSON

Tags: fiware

I am working on FIWARE IoTAgent-JSON. I want to perform device discovery by the same. My expectation from device discovery is that whenever a new device gets registered in IoTAgent-JSON, I receive a notification with device data. Is it possible? If yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a device is registred at IOTA, an entity is created at CB. So, if you create a subscription in CB for that (for instance, a subscription covering all entities of type device) then you can achieve what you want.

You can learn more on CB subscription in [it's corresponding section of the walkthrough documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions).

Comment: Hi @fgalan, thanks for your response. But I want to get notification only once whenever decive is register. If I subscribe to that entity type then it will notify me every time there is an update in values. I tried making use of subscribeContextAvailability, but IOTAgent JSON sends only command in attribute list of registerContext and it does not provide any information about the actual attribute. Please guide me further.

Comment: What about subscribing to the specific entity id corresponding to the device (instead that to the whole entity type)? Would that suffice your use case?